# Jquery utilities scripts, IE, External scripts

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, cookies

I have a very strange problem.
IE throws me error messages when I try to use - JqueryUtilities as $. Cookie. Problem only occurs when I try to access these functions from an external script. If I use these functions in a script page itself they work.

Any idea?

Comment: Show us some code, it's hard to debug without..

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/AZUxM/) - There is a lot of code but this is one of the places..